# Django Rest Framework with nginx caching requests

Tags: django, caching, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

Since I started using DRF with nginx/gunicorn server I've noticed that queries are being cached somehow. I.e. I got 10 records of object A in database (Postrgres) - if I ask for them with GET, I got 10 - ok. But then, when I add another record, I got 10 instead of 11 (although I see 10 in database). I have to manually reset gunicorn to get the correct result, which is not how REST should work...

Here's my nginx config (tried some cache settings):

```
upstream myapp{
  server unix:/var/django/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name myapp.example.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /var/django/myapp/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /var/django/myapp/logs/nginx-error.log;

    # DRF API below
    location /api {
        expires off;
        add_header Cache-Control "private, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;

        proxy_pass http://myapp;

    }
    # JS for webapp (backbone)
    location / {
        alias /var/django/myapp_web/;
    }
}
```

and gunicorn as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="myapp"               
DJANGODIR=/var/django/myapp
SOCKFILE=/var/django/gunicorn.socket 
USER=appuser 
GROUP=appuser
NUM_WORKERS=5    
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings 
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=myapp.wsgi 
TIMEOUT=300

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

cd $DJANGODIR
source /var/django/myapp/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec /var/django/myapp_venv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --reload \
  --timeout $TIMEOUT \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=/var/django/myapp/logs/gunicorn-error.log
  --access-logfile=/var/django/myapp/logs/gunicorn-access.log
```

EDIT
The viewset looks like nothing special:

```
class OrderViewSet(DefaultsMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    queryset = Order.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.GET:
            filter_func = self.request.GET.get('filter', None)
            allowed_filters = ['new', 'open', 'today', 'tomorrow', 'urgent', 'draft']
            if filter_func and filter_func in allowed_filters:
                if hasattr(self.queryset, filter_func):
                    self.queryset = getattr(self.queryset, filter_func)()
                elif filter_func == 'draft':
                    self.queryset = Order.drafts.all()
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.queryset
        elif hasattr(self.request.user, 'driver'):
            if self.request.user.is_staff:
                return self.queryset
            return self.queryset.for_driver(self.request.user.driver)
        elif hasattr(self.request.user, 'employee'):
            return self.queryset.for_employee(self.request.user.employee)
        return self.queryset.filter(user = self.request.user)
```

Comment: If you have to reset gunicorn to see the new values, then it has nothing to do with nginx. The problem almost certainly lies in your Django code; you should post that.

Comment: As Daniel Roseman mentions, this is symptomatic of a queryset being created at a module or class top-level (so yielding the same results for the whole process lifetime).

Comment: Ok, but then why does it work with dev server (runserver + sqllite)?

Comment: because the dev server is reloaded on a regular basis (every time you make a change) (Edit: and I'm seconding previous analysis too)

Comment: Added viewset code

Comment: How do you insert the records in DB? Are you sure this is not because of the ISOLATION LEVEL of your DB?

Comment: I insert records via DRF and Django ORM. They're visible via dbshell. Maybe important fact: the added object is visible when reaching directly for this object with REST (visible in details view, not visible on list view)

Comment: Hi @alekwisnia, have you solved this problem? It appears that I'm having now the exact one.